# Problema com comparação de vetores - Java

Tags: java, array, comparação

Tenho um problema com um codigo simples em Java, comecei agora mesmo a aprender a linguagem.

O exercicio consiste em comparar os valores do vetor para ver se existem elementos repetidos.

O problema, é que me dá sempre 0 no output!

Não sei se tem a ver com o ciclo `while()` ou com o incrementar!

Será que me podiam dar uma dica ? O IDE que uso é o NetBeans 8.1.

Em baixo tem o extrato do codigo responsável por isso, tenho um `System.out.print`, para imprimir o counteúdo do vetor que resulta da junção da `listaA` e `listaB`:

```
    int[] listaA = {2, -5, -121, 102, -35, -2, 0, -125, 802, -10};
    int[] listaB = {6, 99, -1, 12, 1, -2};
    int[] novoVetor;

    novoVetor = new int[listaA.length + listaB.length];  // tamanha do vetor A e o tamanho do vetor B
    int nr_vetorB = listaA.length, rep=0, g=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < listaA.length; i++) {
        novoVetor[i] = listaA[i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < listaB.length; j++) {
        novoVetor[nr_vetorB] = listaB[j];
        nr_vetorB++;
    }


    for (int x = 0; x < novoVetor.length; x++) {
        while( g < novoVetor.length) {
            for (int y = 1; y < novoVetor.length; y++) {
                if (novoVetor[x] == novoVetor[y]) {
                    g = novoVetor.length;
                    rep++;
                } else {
                    g++;
                }


            }

        }
        System.out.print(" " +novoVetor[x]);    
        }

        System.out.print("\nElementos repetidos:" +rep);
```

Cumprimentos

Answer (score -1):

Você poderia fazer diferente:
- Trabalhar somente com os dois arrays que estão sendo comparados, evitando assim a criação do terceiro array e os dois laços de inicialização;
- Na sua estrutura de busca, poderia retirar o while (parece que não se enquadra muito bem de acordo com a finalidade), manter somente os dois "for" onde um varre listaA e o outro a listaB, todos a partir da posição 0, pois é possivel compará-los em separado;
- No if de comparação, não precisaria um else, pois se os elementos forem diferentes, nao há nada a fazer e a busca continua livremente; se forem iguais, então voce pode guardar tanto as posições dos arrays que estão repetidas (criar as variaveis antes de entrar na busca) quanto incrementar o "rep";
- ao final, voce terá o ultimo numero que foi repetido (acessando listaA ou listaB pela posição guardada), e quantas vezes ocorreram repetições.

Comment: Se precisa do array único, então acho que os pontos a serem revisados são somente o while, que na minha opinião não é necessário, e o else que tambem não tem utilidade.

Answer (score -1):

Tente assim:

```
    int[] listaA = {2, -5, -121, 102, -35, -2, 0, -125, 802, -10};
    int[] listaB = {6, 99, -1, 12, 1, -2};
    int[] todos = new int[listaA.length+listaB.length];

    int pt = 0;
    for(int i : listaA){
        todos[pt] = i;
        pt++;
    }
    for(int i : listaB){
        todos[pt] = i;
        pt++;
    }

    int total = 0;
    for(int ptA=0; ptA < todos.length; ptA++){
        for(int ptB=0; ptB < todos.length; ptB++){
            if(ptA == ptB){ // se os ponteiros forem iguais desconsidera..
                continue;
            }
            if(todos[ptA] == todos[ptB]){
                total++;
            }
        }
    }

    total = (total/2); /// pois irá comparar o mesmo item 2 vezes..
    System.out.println("Elementos repetidos: "+total);
```

Comment: obrigado, no exercicio tenho mesmo que criar um vetor com a soma dos dois e fazer a comparação nesse mesmo vetor! muito obrigado mais uma vez :)

Comment: Você só precisa contar quantos tem repetidos? Quando houver regras solicitadas, é interessante que informe na pergunta, assim facilita  a quem for ajudar!